# Best way to implement relationships and enforce database integrity in this situation?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm creating a relatively simple application using CakePHP 2 and MySQL.

There are `Users` for this application, mainly `Admin` users who have access to an admin panel.

Then there are `Customers`. `Customers` can fill out a registration form. Only once the `Customer` has been approved by an `Admin` user, is a User record created for the `Customer` so the customer can log in.

Obviously I need to store the `UserID` against the `CustomerID`, so I can associate the User record with the `Customer` record.

Does this mean I need a third table consisting of just the `UserID` and `CustomerID` that I populate only once the `Customer` has been approved?

EDIT: Just to add, at the moment, each 'Customer' only gets 1 'User', so a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Couldn't you have just a `customer_id` field on your `users` table? (Never mind, I didn't see your question in the post body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you already have two tables in your database:

Table `Users` with `UserID, Name, AccessRights`

Table `Customers` with `CustomerID, Name, OtherSTuff`

Now you want to create a relationship between those tables. The question to ask here is: How many users may exist for a single customer and how many customers may relate to any given user.

I'd personally guess that a single customer could have more than one of their employees accessing your database, but every (non-admin) user would only be associated with one customer. This would be a 1:N relationship: 1 customer has N users. To change your database model accordingly, you just need a `CustomerID` column in your `Users` table.

If my guess was wrong, and 1 user had N customers: one user were to access multiple customers, you'd need a `UserID` column in your `Customers` table.

The only point in time when you'll ever need a *third* table is when N customers have M users, meaning: When a single user can access multiple customers *and* a single customer can be accessed by multiple users.

Edit: I totally omitted the *and enforce database integrity* part.

MySQL supports a `FOREIGN KEY` clause - at least when used with some storage engines, such as InnoDB, I think MyISAM still doesn't. The foreign key clause allows the value in that column to either match an existing value in the foreign table or to be `NULL`. If this behaviour is not desired, you need to declare the column as `NOT NULL`.

You can set up your users so that administrators will have a `CustomerID` of `NULL` while regular users have the `CustomerID` set. But there is a catch to this: Make sure you do not use the `ON DELETE SET NULL` clause, otherwise deleting a customer will make the corresponding user an admin. Use `ON DELETE CASCASE` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear in my question, at the moment it's a 1:1 relationship, each customer only gets 1 user.

I initially thought I could just put a `CustomerID` in the `Users` table, but for admin users the `CustomerID` would be NULL, so I can't then enforce integrity of the relationship, can I?

Comment: You can use InnoDB's FOREIGN KEY clause on columns with NULL values. There's just one catch: do not use the ON DELETE SET NULL clause, otherwise deleting a customer will make the corresponding user an admin. Use ON DELETE CASCASE instead.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks Hazzit. Shall I mark your answer as correct, or do you want to move your comment to a separate post and I'll mark that as the answer?